# Create account using Spark -> Openfire

Tags: macos, localhost, openfire, xmppframework

I having problem while creating account using spark. even i can't able to login using credentials of openFire created user.

actually the domain name

> Java Version:    1.8.0_111 Oracle Corporation -- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit
>   Server VM
>       Appserver:    jetty/9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
>       Server Host Name (FQDN):   Java Version:  1.8.0_111 Oracle Corporation -- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
>   Appserver:    jetty/9.2.z-SNAPSHOT Server Host Name (FQDN):   192.168.0.103

i used to create account by name password and domain name 192.168.0.103.
But this error occur

> could not connect to Ip Addredd

I even tried different server name that is 127.0.0.1 that is localhost.

actually openfire is installed on my local address that is http://localhost:9090/index.jsp

**Here is the screenshot of openfire that have XMPP Domain name not server name**
[image]

**Screenshot of spark Advance setting.**

[image]
Please help i am in trouble

Answer (score 1):

[image]

it is simple, just uncheck the first box and check the second, the one you see in my picture.

Answer (score 0):

If Openfire it's correctly up and running, as "server name" in Spark's input login mask you have to insert the server-name and not the IP HOST, like in example  screenshot (your name will be different):

[image]

Comment: Here is the screenshot of openfire that have XMPP Domain name not server name

Comment: i exactly written same XMPP Domain name. but it give error certificate hostname verification failed

Comment: Without a domain a server can't manage messages! You have to set this value, as example Insert into "GATE_OPENFIRE".OFPROPERTY (NAME,PROPVALUE) values ('xmpp.domain','mad-burea'); or add by user interface (system properties). Then restart openfire and use this value (after checking by admin panel like you just did)

Comment: Sorry to interrupt you.. i am newbie.. openfire is installed locally so it's domain is just localhost:9090 then how to set value that you have specified

Comment: then the domain is "localhost", not "localhost:9090", but i don't read this in your screenshot, seems to not be setted. As I said, execute the update in your database manually or go in System Properties (it's the next option on the left in your screenshot, after System Information) and add by bottom-form

Comment: Yes i have added and used while logging but it give me error that prompt certificate hostname verification failed